# setting sampling time in c mex s func

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, mex

What is the equivalent of the following for a C-mex s function? That is, how do I set discrete sample time of a block to the top level fixed step size in C?

My problem is, I could not find a way to "get" the top level fixed step size parameter in C-mex.

```
function setup(block)
  block.SampleTimes = [str2double(get_param(bdroot, 'FixedStep')) 0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ssGetFixedStepSize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/ssgetfixedstepsize.html) to get the base rate of the model. You may also want to [`ssSetErrorStatus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/ssseterrorstatus.html) if the that call returns `0`, because that means your model is not configured with a `FixedStep` solver.

If, for some reason, you really want to go about fetching the information similar to what you have in the question, then you might be able to get access to it if you dig through the `SimStruct` pointer's fields. To do this, breakpoint in the mex file using a debugger and watch that variable.

Another option would be a few [`mexCallMATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html) calls to get the information you want.